# Low mic gain on bluetooth headset with new Android

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, headset

I have been using Sennheiser HD350 headset since 2 years now. I have taken many many calls with this headset on various OS including Android, MacOS and Windows. Never had any issues. However, I recently changed my Android phone and the new phone supports Bluetooth v5.3.

Now when I take calls from this headset via this andorid phone, the receiver can hear me but complains of very low volume (low mic gain). The same headset performs well with other android and windows devices.

This is what I have tried so far:-

- Updated the headset to latest version
- Did a factory reset which removes all pairings
- Re-paired with new phone
- Reached out to Sennheiser customer care

Note: My brother also got the same headset with me and he is also facing same issue when taking calls from Windows laptop.

Please suggest.